# Hibernate+Spring JPA: Bidirectional oneToMany firing insert query twice

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

In a spring boot application, I have parent child entities. Parent has many childs. Parent has oneToMany defined for List of childs and Child has manyToOne for Parent object. When I try to insert, log shows queries are fired twice for each insert.

**Parent.java**

```
public class Parent {

  @javax.persistence.Id
  @Column(name = "PARENT_ID")
  //sequence generator
  private Long parentId;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
  private List<Child> childs;

//getters and setters
}
```

**Child.java**

```
public class Child {

  //constructor

  @javax.persistence.Id
  @Column(name = "CHILD_ID")
  //sequence generator
  private Long childId;

  @Column(name="NAME")
  private String childName;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="PARENT_ID")
  Parent parent;

  //getters and setters
}
```

**Repository call**

```
Parent p = new Parent();
List<Child> childs = Arrays.asList(new Child("child1", p), new 
Child("child2", p));
p.setChilds(childs);

//call to save entity
parentRepository.save(p);
```

When I execute this statement, I see 2 select statements, 2 insert statements for parent, 4 insert statements for child. My expection was 1 insert for parent and 2 insert for child.

Is this how its supposed to be or I am doing something wrong?

Comment: Are there actually duplicate rows in the database?

Comment: No. In the db table, there are unique entries and no duplicates.

Comment: Can you post the logs that are showing these statements?

Comment: How did you configure the Hibernate logger?

Comment: I added debug for hibernate.sql in log4j.xml. <Logger name="org.hibernate.SQL" level="debug">
      <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
    </Logger>

Comment: While checking the configuration for logs and the logs in the console, I realized just the logs were printed twice for each execution. So, the problem was log configuration and nothing was wrong with hibernate setup. Thank you all for your help